# what is about the corresponding power series?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces, power-series

According to the papers [The absolutely continuous spectrum of Jacobi matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1101) and [these lecture notes](https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/alexander.pushnitski/ebd65/simon.pdf):

- periodicity ~ potential well or lattice (order)
- lack of absolutely continued spectrum ~ Anderson localization(disorder)

Given this, what is the corresponding spectrum of a particle in quasi-order materials (like quasicrystals，quasi-order)? or what is about corresponding power series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quasiperiodic potentials, such as the [Fibonacci chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_quasicrystal), have a spectrum that is called [singular continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution), with a fractal structure, see

- [Fractal energy spectrum of a polariton gas in a Fibonacci quasi-periodic potential](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3453) (2013)
- [From the Hofstadter
  to the Fibonacci butterfly](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0610192) (2006)
- [Schrödinger difference
  equation with deterministic ergodic potentials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3646) (2012)
- [Cantor spectrum for the quasi-periodic Schrödinger equation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002203969190133T) (1991)
- [Operators with singular continuous spectrum: Almost periodic Schrödinger operators](http://www.math.caltech.edu/papers/bsimon/p236.pdf) (1992)

Comment: Your opening sentence is incorrect, other types of spectrum (such as absolutey continuous or pure point spectrum) are also possible for quasi-periodic potentials.

Comment: Also, the potential of the Fibonacci Hamiltonian is not quasi-periodic. I think you confused quasicrystals and quasi-periodic sequences.

Comment: @ChristianRemling why do you not clarify these ideas and answer the questions?

Comment: @XL_at_China: To be totally honest, I find your question hard to answer (and understand, in fact) since it's so very general and vague. If you just wanted more material, then Carlo's answer provides that. Sorry for the unsolicited advice, but in my experience at least, concrete, to the point questions tend to work better on this site.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Surely I want more material. But one question is about your article and Simon's article. One conclusion is related to power series: if the coefficients $a_i$are finite($a_i \in A, A is finite$), the sequence of the coefficients $[a_0,a_1,a_2.....]$ will be eventually periodic or random. I think possibly what  randomness means in your article, is it consistent with Kolmogorov's definition or Chaitin's definition? Maybe it includes more than strict random sequence in the Kolmogorov's randomness sense. About the randomness, see Kolmogorov, Chaitin, or [to be continued]

Comment: [continue] https://www.cwi.nl/~paulv/kolmogorov.html

Comment: @XL_at_China: No, randomness in this context has nothing to do with Kolmogorov complexity. Eventually periodic and random sequences (in a precise technical sense) are just two possible scenarios that do not even begin to exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: @ChristianRemling but any other definition of randomness except Kolmogorov or the like is not consistent with our intuition about probability and statistics. So the sequence which eventually is random must include some quasi periodic sequence which may correspond to quasicrystal or the like..

Comment: @ChristianRemling  In fact randomness can only be strictly defined in  Kolmgorov, Chaitin's sense.

Comment: With a vague or undefinable idea, the theorem would have a flaw.

Comment: @ChristianRemling   Excuse me. If we do not use the randomness in the Kolmogorov sense, the theorem " if the coefficients $a_i$ are finite($a_i \in A,A $ is finite), the sequence of the coefficients $[a_0,a_1,a_2.....]$ will be eventually periodic or random" will become " if the coefficients $a_i$ are finite($a_i \in A,A $ is finite), the sequence of the coefficients $[a_0,a_1,a_2.....]$ will be eventually periodic or non-periodic", which is meaningless. Have I misunderstood you?