# Is the value of the power series at 0.1 transcendental?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, power-series

Let $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x^n$$ where $a_n\in \{0,1\}$, and the $f(x)$ has a natural boundary. By the way, $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x^n$$ is rational function or transcendental one on $\mathbb{C}$。

Is $f(x)$ at $\frac{1}{10}$ transcendental? Or is the value of such a transcendental function of power series  at  $\frac{1}{10}$ a transcendental number?

UPDATE: in addition, let $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x^n$$ where $a_n\in \mathbb{N},\exists M\in \mathbb{N}, a_n < M$, and the $f(x)$ has a natural boundary. Is $f(x)$ at $\frac{1}{10}$ transcendental?

Comment: Doesn't it obviously depend on what the $a_n$s are? E.g. if each $a_n$ is $1$, then $f({1\over 10})={1\over9}$, but another choice of $a_n$s gives Liouville's constant.

Comment: Maybe linking to this wiki page can clear up some confusion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function

Comment: @NoahSchweber, an∈{0,1} , and the f(x) has a natural boundary. It means an is random on {0,1} , please have a look at article of such a series like relating part of 
 the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0823, or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273835/what-is-about-the-corresponding-power-series.

Comment: @SamHopkins, the wiki can not cover all cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is likely open.

We can tell whether $f(1/10)$ is rational or irrational (by asking whether $a_n$ is eventually periodic); in this case, definitely irrational.

Can we have an **algebraic** irrational whose expansion base $10$ consists only of $0$s and $1$s?  It is believed that is impossible, but has not been proved.  Indeed, it is believed that algebraic irrational numbers are normal in all bases.

Similar question: is there an algebraic irrational point in the middle-thirds Cantor set?

Comment: Any reference please

Answer (score 6):

For the UPDATE, allowing coefficients $a_n < M$ for a fixed $M$.  Then there are examples with $f(1/10)$ rational.

Let's do this.  Define a sequence $(a_n)$ of coefficients as follows:  Start with a rapidly increasing sequence $(t_k)$ of natural numbers with $t_{k+1} > t_k+3$.  Let
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
2 \quad & n=t_k\text{ for some }k
\\
13\quad & n=t_k+1\text{ for some }k
\\
3 \quad &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now our series is $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$.  Most of the digits are $3$s, but occasionally there is a $2$ followed by a $13$.  Because the sequence $(t_k)$ is lacunary, $f(x)$ has a natural boundary at its radius of convergence.  But of course $f(1/10) = 1/3$.

Comment: Excellent，and thanks